# Mac Files hidden but visible from Windows PC

Tags: windows, network-share, mac, files, hidden

I'm new to the forum here. and i am having an issue that is starting to occur more and more over the last few days.

With the Macs, InDesign files are created and edited on a day to day basis and some times when one of these files gets saved it will then become invisible on the Mac but totally visible and normal when looking at the file on a windows machine.
These files are saved on a windows network drive.

These can also randomly get turned invisible.

I am going to test with deleting caches tomorrow on a test mac but does anyone here have any idea of how to prevent this. To fix the issue i have to go onto a mac and show invisible files using the terminal command to then re-save under a different name so it is not invisible. Then delete the invisible file. And re-do a terminal command to hide all hidden files again. (I cant have invisible files showing all the time as it is too messy.)

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Harvey

Comment: The files dont happen to start with a '.' ?

Comment: Note that StackExchange sites are not "forums".

Answer (score 0):

You can hide files/folders in Mac just by prefixing the filename with a dot `(.filename)` which will remain visible in Windows, so if you named the Windows files with a leading dot, you'd have that covered. OS X also supports an 'invisible' attribute, which, given that it's not recognized by Windows, would most likely hide the Windows files from OS X while leaving them visible to Windows...but this would likely have to be set from OS X. The reverse is a bit more tricky if you're working from OS X, but a similar question got a couple of suggestions for how to do this. Otherwise, if you just set the 'hidden' attribute in Windows, OS X should just ignore it. You could then set this attribute for the Mac files, which would hide them from Windows.

Comment: Hi, We are also running Mountain lion if this help.No dots are on any of the file names apart form before the file extension. I need the files to be visible on both Windows and Macs...